# Calling a function from a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have been using/calling functions from objects like this:

```
var object = { 
    fn: function(){ 
        alert('i can see it!'); 
    }
}; 
object.fn(); // it works
```

but I don't know how to call function from mere `{}` object.

```
{
    fn: function() {
        alert('i can\'t see it');
    }
}

fn(); // wont work ?
```

I want to know why this is not working? Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: It's not working because you haven't given a name to the object (which is a block scope, rather than an 'object') that defines where it should 'look' to find the function.

Comment: A simple fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/6LUwZ/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second example is invalid syntax. The `{}` is interpreted as a block statement with a label and an invalid function because it has no name.

If you wanted to do it inline like that, you'd need something more like this:

```
({
    fn: function() {
        alert('now i can see it');
    }
}).fn();
```

Now you're creating an object since the `{}` can no longer be a block statement, but is instead object literal syntax. Then you're immediately accessing the `fn` property you defined.

Of course there's little point to this, but it's closer to what you were doing.

Comment: @user2168042 - that's great, but as noted in the answer, doing it like this makes absolutely no sense ?

Answer (score 1):

fn is inside the blocks and  not inside the object. Passing name-value just inside blocks ie {} dont work. Or atleast give some label to the block.

Answer (score 0):

Call it like so: `object.fn();`. As @BlueSkies said, the second example will not work, as it is invalid syntax. You can't do that in JavaScript. If you name that object like David said in the comments, then it will work. You can't call a function out of an anonymous object.

Here is an example with the object being called `e`: http://jsfiddle.net/dhF5k/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper syntax to define a "standalone" function (with no wrapper object) :

```
var fn = function () { ... };
function fn() { ... };
```

Comment: The brackets were actually balanced properly. It's just that there was another one hiding at the end of the `alert();`. I edited the question... waiting for peer review.